# Cybersource Paymentgetway integration for android

Tags: android, payment-gateway

In my android app i want to integrate cybersource  payment getway.but not found proper doucmentation related to api.
I also not sure this api is available for android or not.
So Please help me in integrate this api.
[This link](http://www.cybersource.com/)for cyber security official site.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use this SDK
CyberSource Simple Order API for Java
https://github.com/CyberSource/cybersource-sdk-java

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Answer (score 0):

This question has nothing to do with Android. You'll have to talk to cybersource support with regards to their API. As long as they have a REST/Soap API, it will work with Android no problem.

Comment: thanks for your answer, some payment gateway provide sdk or api for mobile platform.so if there is any sdk related to my search then i was looking for it.I have also posted on support but still not getting answer.

Comment: @rb16 Ah I see. I apologize for being so rash. I've never worked with cybersource before so I'm not sure if they have an android specific lib sorry.